# Can projective objects in triangulated categories be detected via Hom vanishing?

Tags: category-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Projective objects can be defined in any category https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_object.  Now let $(T,\Sigma)$ be a triangulated category. Then, is it true that an object $X$ in $T$ is a projective object if and only if $\text{Hom}_T(\Sigma^{-1}X,Y)=0$ for all $Y \in T$ ?

I believe this holds in the derived category of $R$-modules (for any ring $R$) which motivates my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a triangulated category, the only epimorphisms are the split epimorphisms, (see, for example, [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15662) for a proof of the dual fact that every monomorphism splits). From this it follows that *every* object in a triangulated category is projective.